# Can explicitly defaulted / deleted functions overload on ref qualifiers?

Tags: c++, c++11

### INTRO

- [**Ref qualifiers**](http://akrzemi1.wordpress.com/2014/06/02/ref-qualifiers/) : A way to dissambiguate the rl-valuness of the implied object. As a quick example, take the following class

  ```
  class example
  {
    int member;
  public:
    // ...
    int&       value() &;
    //                 ^
    int&&      value() &&;
    //                 ^^
    int const& value() const&;
    //                      ^
  };
  ```

  The use of this C++11 feature (syntax marked with `^`), allows us to control the version of `value()` that will be called with

  - l-values
  - temporaries
  - const l-values

  Practically the ref qualification applies to the classe's `*this`
- [**Defaulted / Deleted functions**](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2007/n2210.html) : Specify a *special member function* as having the compiler generated (**default**) definition or inaccessible (**delete**). As an example take

  ```
  struct type {
    type(const type&)            = delete;
    type& operator=(const type&) = delete;
  };
  ```

  The above struct, achieves **being non copyable** with extremely clear semantics

### QUESTIONs

- Is it possible / valid to **combine these features** ?
- Which are the cases where it's **explicitly forbidden** or **bad style** ?
- Is there any **use case / pattern** for such a combination ? (Eg creating conditional interfaces based rl-valueness quick and easy)

Comment: Somewhat related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20886466/should-the-assignment-operator-observe-the-assigned-objects-rvalueness

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, but there's not much use, as constructors and destructors can't be ref-qualified.

You can ref-qualify assignment operators:

```
struct S {
  S &operator=(const S &) && = default;
};

int main() {
  S s;
  S() = s;  // OK
  s = S();  // error - LHS must be an rvalue
}
```

However, I'm somewhat at a loss to imagine what this would be useful for.

Comment: Since you can `= delete` just about anything, this is very useful for clear error messages (instead of "overload not found").